# Looking for SQA tutorials in hindi or urdu

Tags: manual-testing

I am looking for sqa tutorials in hindi language or in urdu. Tried to search on google, but did not find. If anyone knows, please share here.

Comment: I don't think there are any SQA related tutorials available in urdu language. Your best bet would be finding SQA audio/video lectures delivered in urdu/hindi language. You can start from virtual university pakistan lectures on SQA.

Comment: http://vuhelp.pk/group/cs706-software-quality-assurance/forum/topics/software-quality-assurance-cs706-download-complete-lectures-1-45

Answer (score 2):

For hindi videos you can go through this youtube channel

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzzX3aRVSwbibplmiwJ3ujg

This channel includes all technical videos in Hindi.

Comment: @Muhammad Ali Khamis Please let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are many solutions for Software quality assurance.

You can easily learn from vu help corner. There are Urdu language courses as well at:
http://vuhelpcorner.com/groups/cs706-software-quality-assurance/forum/

Answer (score 0):

You can watch SQA hindi tutorials of Ajaze Khan. He has related SQA videos in hindi also. Please have a look.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZ_BiPLgTfo